# .net core mvc Mocking Identity and claims and test if user has claim

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to unit test my controller logic, it's a (.Net core 2 mvc App) I have a controller that returns details of an item if the user has specific claim, and I want to unit test that using XUnit.

Here is the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var controlException = await _context.ControlException.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (controlException == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    if (User.HasClaim("control Claim", "control Claim"))
    {
            return View(controlException);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Account");
    }

}
```

My Unit test code is : (`GetContextWithData()` return InMemory test Database)

```
[Fact]
public async Task VerifyDetailsViewType()
{

    using (var context = GetContextWithData())
    using (var _controller = new ControlExceptionsController(context))
    {      
        var userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
                         userStore.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        var cp = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();
        cp.Setup(m => m.HasClaim(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
          .Returns(true);
        cp.Setup(m => m.Identity).Returns(identityMock.Object);

        _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"] = "http://www.test.nl";

        var result = await _controller.Details(888);
        Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
    }
}
```

My test failed because the result is "`RedirectToAction`" and not "`ViewResult`".

I know because the user does't have the claim, so the question is how can I assign a claim to the user, in other words how can I mock the `Identity` and claims and manage this.

Comment: Where do you assign the user of the controller in the test? You mock it up but I do not see where you assign it to the user.

Comment: When I assign the claim to thr user :
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("control Claim", "control Claim"));
I get this error : NotSupportedException : Store does not implement IUserClaimStore<TUser>.

Comment: No, you assign the principal to the `User` of the context. `_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User = cp.Object;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the principal to the controller to allow the code to exercise to completion as desired.

You mock the principal but do not assign it to the controller in the test.

```
_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User = cp.Object;
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi  that is it.